# CKEditor сохранить/загрузить текст в/из файла

Tags: javascript

Доброго всем дня.

Я пытаюсь с помощью `JavaScript` текст из `CKEditor` сохранить в файл или загрузить из файла, но пока безрезультатно.
Я долго пытался найти что-то в Интернете, но до сих пор смог это реализовать только с помощью `PHP`.
Можете ли вы дать мне небольшой пример, как сделать это с помощью `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 0):

Вот мини текстовый редактор, в который можно загрузить текст из файла, отредактировать и сохранить обратно.

```js
let file_name = 'Result.txt';
const textarea = document.getElementById('text');
// editor = CKEDITOR.replace(textarea); 
const files = document.getElementById('files');

// Создать файл
function generate_file(data){
    data = new Blob(["\ufeff", [data]], {type:'plain/text'});
    return window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
}

// Прочесть файл
function read_file(file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
        const text = reader.result;
        textarea.value = text;
        // Для CKEditor вместо строчки выше:
        // editor.setData(text);
        make_download(text, file.name);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

// Создание ссылки для скачивания
function make_download(content, name = file_name){
    const download_link = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    download_link.innerText = name;
    download_link.download = name;
    download_link.href = generate_file(content);
}

// Вешаем обработчики
files.addEventListener('change', () => {
    read_file(files.files[0]);
    file_name = files.files[0].name;
}, false);

textarea.onchange = e => make_download(textarea.value)
/* Для CKEditor, вместо строчки выше пишем - 
editor.on('change', () => {
    make_download(editor.getData())
});
он почему то не хочет работать в сниппетах */
```

```css
textarea{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea><br/>
<input type="file" id="files" /><br/>
<a download='result.txt'>Download</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужен пример именно с CKEditor

Comment: Для CKEditor всё практически то же самое, разница только в том, как вешать обработчик и как получать из него текст. добавил примерный код в конец